# How to get the count of item by deducting the state

Tags: postgresql

I need you guys to help me on my query :)

Let say i have this `line_item` table:

| id | order_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | reserved |
| 2 | 11 | to-ship |
| 3 | 11 | pending |
| 4 | 22 | confirmed |
| 5 | 22 | to-ship |
| 6 | 33 | pending |
| 7 | 33 | reserved |
| 8 | 33 | canceled |
| 9 | 33 | to-ship |

I can retrieve, for each `order` (`order_id`) its state by this order list:
`['pending', 'reserved', 'to-ship', 'confirmed', 'unavailable', 'canceled']`

With this kind of query, i can have the state of each order (if an order has at least one item on state `pending`, the order is considering as `pending`. If an order has two items, on with the state `confirmed` and the other with the state `reserved`, the order should be considered as `reserved`).

```
WITH statuses_rank AS (
  SELECT ARRAY['pending', 'reserved', 'to-ship', 'confirmed', 'unavailable', 'canceled'] AS statuses_order
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (order_id) order_id, status
FROM line_item, statuses_rank
ORDER BY order_id, array_position(statuses_order, status::text);
```

I'll have this result:

| order_id | statuses |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | pending |
| 22 | to-ship |
| 33 | pending |

It's perfect!

**But now**, I need to get the number of order considered as `pending`, `reserved`, ...
I would like to have this kind of result:

| count(order_id) | statuses |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | pending |
| 1 | to-ship |

So i tried this, but, it's not working:

```
WITH statuses_rank AS (
  SELECT ARRAY['pending', 'reserved', 'to-ship', 'confirmed', 'unavailable', 'canceled'] AS statuses_order
)
SELECT  status, COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) as count_order
FROM line_item, statuses_rank
GROUP BY status, statuses_rank.statuses_order
ORDER BY array_position(statuses_order, status::text) ASC;
```

Do you guys have any idea about this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your query as a derived table:

```sql
WITH statuses_rank AS (
  SELECT ARRAY[
    'pending', 'reserved', 'to-ship', 
    'confirmed', 'unavailable', 'canceled'] AS statuses_order
)
SELECT count(*), status
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (order_id) order_id, status
    FROM line_item, statuses_rank
    ORDER BY order_id, array_position(statuses_order, status::text)
    ) s
GROUP BY status;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/l4q-5c1d)